# android app using picasso works on samsung galaxy s4 but not on galaxy s8

Tags: android, picasso, samsung-galaxy

On my firestore db app, I am fetching google photos by URL address and using picasso to display the image view. It works efficiently on my Samsung Galaxy S4 but does not work at all on my Samsung S8.
The relevant code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.encounters_detail);
txtdt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dt);                    
txtdt.setText(model.getDate().toString());
txtencounter= 
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_encounter);
txtencounter.setText(model.getEncounter().
toString();
photourl=(model.getPhotoURL().toString());
String urlString = photourl;
try {
URL myURL = new URL(urlString);
photourl = myURL.toString();
 }catch (Exception e){
 }

 imgvw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

 Picasso.with(context).load(photourl).
    fit().into(imgvw);
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are both phones giving equal permissions (esp. network permission)? Can you add the phones' Android versions in the post?

Comment: Android version Galaxy s4 5.01, S8 7.0

Comment: Android version Galaxy s4 5.01, S8 7.0 How do I check permissions? I should add that  also 2 textfields on the layout display normally. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In running the app in debug mode and invoking the above code I got two different responses in the android studio Console. For the Galaxy S4 that displays the image:

Answer (score -1):

Please try Glide ...
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library
It's more effective then Picasso..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question